# My sql query can't show my desired result

Tags: mysql

I have following tables:

```
 comitees: Id, Name

 comitee_member: Id, Cid, Mid, C_Month

 Reference: Id, Mid, Cid, Month, Ref_Number

 user_type: Id, User_Name, Ref_Number

 notifications: Id, Sender_Name, Reciever_Name, Month
```

I want to send a notification:

Suppose Mr. A has `comitee_member.C_Month=9/9/2015`. When Mr. B submits his reference number for `reference.Month=9/9/2015`, Mr. A recieves a notification that shows the sender's name (Mr. B), `comitees.Name`, and the `reference.Month` when `comitee` was submitted. This data must be stored in the `Notifications` table.

I have this so far:

```
Select us.Id, 
       c.Name, 
       cm.C_Month, 
       u.User_Name AS Receiver, 
       us.User_Name AS Sender 
FROM  user_type u, 
      user_type us 
INNER JOIN reference r ON us.Id = r.Mid
INNER JOIN comitee_member cm ON r.Month = cm.C_Month
INNER JOIN comitees c ON c.Id = r.Cid
WHERE us.Id = 3 (suppose)
```

Comment: Show us the code you have that doesn't work

Comment: show us some sample data.

Comment: The above querry dosent show the right result
I want to show this in data base
Sender_Name : Reciever_Name   : Comitee.Name  : C_Month
Mr B                    Mr A                          abc2015             9/9/2015

Comment: The above querry dosent show the right result
I want to show this in notification table in data base insert is not such prblem but selecting this

Sender_Name : Reciever_Name   : Comitee.Name  : C_Month

Mr B                    Mr A                          abc2015             9/9/2015

Comment: How is the relation between reference and receiver? Is it ref_number? Can you please cut irrelevant attributes? Maybe we need only: > comitees: Id, Name >  > comitee_member: Id, Cid, Mid, C_Month
 > 
 > Reference: Id, Mid, Cid, Month, Ref_Number
 > 
 > user_type: Id, User_Name, Ref_Number
 > 
 > notifications: Id, Sender_Name, Reciever_Name, Month

Comment: I guess these relationships from your sql statement: Reference.mid --> user_type(id). Reference.cid --> comitees(id). Reference.month --> comitee_member(C_month). But I miss some relationships. I this right? comitee_member.mid --> user_type(id)? comitee_member.cid --> comitees(id)?

Comment: And btw, do we need ref_number?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. it's best to clarify your question by editing it rather than by adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

I guess these relationships from your sql statement:

- Reference.mid --> user_type(id)
- Reference.cid --> comitees(id)
- Reference.month --> comitee_member(C_month)

I miss some relationships.
If this is right:

- comitee_member.mid --> user_type.id?

you can get your results with

```
Select uSender.Id, 
   c.Name, 
   cm.C_Month, 
   uReceiver.User_Name AS Receiver, 
   uSender.User_Name AS Sender 
FROM user_type uSender
JOIN reference r ON uSender.Id = r.Mid
JOIN comitees c ON c.Id = r.Cid
JOIN comitee_member cm ON r.Month = cm.C_Month
JOIN user_type uReceiver ON uReceiver.Id = cm.Mid;
```

Optional you can add your where clause.
Btw, I used the short form of `INNER JOIN`, just `JOIN`.